# Typescript library: Hide internal exports

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, shared-libraries

I am building a library in typescript that is being published via npm.

In the index.ts, which is the starting point of the library, all the public classes and enums are exported.

```
import { MyClass } from './internal/my-class'
import { MyEnum } from './internal/my-enum'
export { MyClass, MyEnum }
```

This works well, but I noticed that users are able to import internal functions/classes etc. as well by using a direct path to the file.

```
// in a project that installed my library as an npm dependency
import { InternalClass } from 'my-lib/dist/internal/internal-class'
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

I need to "export" `InternalClass` because I'm importing and using it throughout my library, but I don't want to expose it publicly. I tried using namespaces, but couldn't really get it to work.

Comment: What solution did you use in the end? facing the same issue

Comment: Looking for an official support on:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41316
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41425

Answer (score 17):

You should set the `stripInternal` flag in your `tsconfig.json` (or from the command line) to `true` and use tsdoc comments with the `@internal` tag.

```
// internal/my_file.ts
/** @internal */
export function myInternalFunction() {}
```

Note that this will remove the function from the type declarations, so it that it will not autocomplete in editors, but if you really need to hide internal details I suggest you bundle your code using [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) with the TypeScript plugin.

Comment: It will not autocomplete for library users but it will autocomplete while I'm developing the library, correct? As for Rollup it doesn't seem to support `d.ts`: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/568. Ideally I want my users to be able to dig into the internals of the source code with automcomplete etc. (in case they are curious) but I don't want them to be able to use any internals.

Comment: stripInternal only affects the type declarations (`.d.ts` files) emitted not the code emitted, you are correct only code NOT marked as `@internal` will autocomplete for your users. If you want to rollup `.d.ts` files use `@microsoft/api-extractor` which is officially maintained by Microsoft.

Comment: So that you can use api extractor for `.d.ts` (it only handles type declarations) and Rollup for the actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Using [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) or similar tools to bundle your package.
It should generate 1 file and your users can only import from that entry point.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can.

I suppose you can use TS's modules to compile into JS's IIFE, [as described by Lucas Morgan here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60684239/3290062), but I there's not much point doing that. If you publish open source, there's no stopping anyone from extracting any part of your code.

Comment: Sure but it's about making it more explicit to users what should and what shouldn't be used. It's also about decluttering Intelisense. It happened to me in the past that I mistakenly used an internal API without knowing that I shouldn't have used it.

Comment: Yup. There is value in clearly communicating to callers of your library what you will (and will not) support (see: "Hyrum's Law"). The more freedom you leave the callers, the less specific knowledge you have about your own problem, which limits the types of bugs you can fix, especially when performance is a concern (because performance is always implicit... as in you cannot directly control physics, just accommodate it).