# Import into an object? Best practices for organizing a module library

Tags: javascript, module, components

Hi  I want to create a module library with a set of helper functions. Not sure where to put the code to keep everything organized, was first thinking to create it like:

```
lib-name
 - main.js
 - some-module
    - some-part-of-the-module.js
    - some-other-part-of-the-module.js
```

*However* when accessing the objects in the library, I would like to be able to use dot scoping, like

```js
lib-name.some-module.some-thing("This is a function argument!");
```

both to avoid ODR violations & avoid having 10-50 lines worth of imports.

How would I best set this up? Was hoping for a completely vanilla solution, though if there are any common libraries for this sort of thing out there Im all ears. Im writing my project completely without frontend frameworks and using a flask backend (the latter of which I dont think is relevant?). Would ideally like to avoid having to use a build system at the very least.

*Have been looking a bit already at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules, but it seems that `import` doesn't support importing into existing objects - making it difficult to achieve my . accessor dream without too much of a hassle.*

Comment: if i were you, i would create a `js` file to act as a bridge between the callers and the module. in the bridge file i would import all of the modules, put them in an object and export that object out for the callers.

Comment: Thank you @Layhout . Would that look something like this?


```import {someFunction} from './some-module/some-part-of-the-module.js'
import {someOtherFunction} from './some-module/some-other-part-of-the-module.js'
let libName = {
    someFunction: someFunction,
    someOtherFunction: someOtherFunction
}
```.

And then I suppose I would import that via `import {libName} from "lib-name.main.js";` ?

Is main.js a suitable name? Or are there more common/standardized naming conventions I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just my idea and there might be a better way of doing this. continue from my comment, here what i would do:

```
libname/
  some-module/
    some-part-of-the-module.js
    some-other-part-of-the-module.js
  index.js
```

the `index.js` is the bridge file. inside it would be like:

```js
import { someFunction } from './some-module/some-part-of-the-module.js';
import { someOtherFunction } from './some-module/some-other-part-of-the-module.js';

const libname = {
  someFunction,
  someOtherFunction
}

export default libname;
```

and when you want to use, you would do something like:

```js
import libname from "libname";

libname.someFunction();
libname.someOtherFunction();
```

note: the bridge file's named `index.js` because when your import something from it, you don't need to specify the file name.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the index.js naming trick, certainly better than calling it main.js then!

Comment: Adding to this, is it possible to hide "someFunction" & "someOtherFunction", to prevent someone from using them outside of the "libname" object?

Comment: i don't think javascript can do that. as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122428/typescript-library-hide-internal-exports), to do that, you'll need to ether write your library with typescript (.ts files) or bundle your library with a bundler. note: if you go into node_module folder and take a look inside a library folder, you'll see some typescript.

Comment: tool like [ESLint](https://mtsknn.fi/blog/eslint-import-restrictions/) can help as well.

Comment: https://www.webtips.dev/prevent-imports-with-eslint

Comment: Actually I decided to declare my functions directly under each file and use `import * as someSubmodule from './some-submodule.js'`, then inside `.some-submodule.js` I can use that `import * as whatever` again to start building a hierarchy.

That way it becomes a little bit like the import system in Python & I can access my functions like `import libname; libname.someSubmodule.someSubModuleOfTheSubModule.someFunction();` when using the library. It also makes autocompletion work in VS Code(which was an unexpected bonus)!